# Aggregate with max and addfield using mongodb driver C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a query like this in mongodb:

```
db.Product.aggregate([
 { $addFields: { maxSku: { $max: '$ProductVariants.FullSku' } } },
 { $group: { _id: null, value: { $max: '$maxSk' } } }
])
```

but how can I execute it using mongodb driver (linq) in C#?

I've tried to use `db.RunCommandAsync` but that's not working

```
var command = new JsonCommand<BsonDocument>("db.Product.aggregate([{ $addFields: { maxSku: { $max: '$ProductVariants.FullSku' } } },{ $group: { _id: null, value: { $max: '$maxSk' } } }])");
var result = await _productRepository.Database.RunCommandAsync<BsonDocument(command);
```

the error is

```
JSON reader was expecting a value but found 'db'.
at MongoDB.Bson.IO.JsonReader.ReadBsonType()...etc
```

Comment: *not working* isn't extremely helpful .... what happens? Do you get an error? If so: **what** error? Does it not do anything at all? Does it do something (*what?*) but not you expected (*so what DID you expect?*) ?

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is wrong, `RunCommand` runs a single command (ie `insert/aggregate and etc`), this has nothing common with the shell syntax you use (the shell can use own helpers that noone else implements).
What you need is to run Aggregate command with raw `BsonDocument`s as stages. [See](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68395490/how-to-use-raw-mongodb-aggregation-query-in-c/68397480#68397480) for details

Answer (score 0):

[@dododo provides the right guidance and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74125989/20042973).

I'm just stopping by to mention that you can use MongoDB Compass to help translate between aggregation pipelines defined in the shell to code for the drivers. Using [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73876002/20042973) with the pipeline text from your question, the following is produced for C#:

```
new BsonArray
{
    new BsonDocument("$addFields", 
    new BsonDocument("maxSku", 
    new BsonDocument("$max", "$ProductVariants.FullSku"))),
    new BsonDocument("$group", 
    new BsonDocument
        {
            { "_id", BsonNull.Value }, 
            { "value", 
    new BsonDocument("$max", "$maxSk") }
        })
}
```

Using LINQ to build your queries is different, there is a blog post from earlier this year [here](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/languages/csharp/using-linq-query-mongodb-dotnet-core-application/) that might be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

I had solved it  like this

```
var bson = await _productRepository.Collection.Aggregate()
                 .AppendStage<BsonDocument>(BsonDocument.Parse(" { $addFields: { maxSku: { $max: \"$ProductVariants.FullSku\" } } }"))
                 .AppendStage<BsonDocument>(BsonDocument.Parse("{ $group: { _id: null, value: { $max: \"$maxSku\" } } }"))
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```